# STS first springmvcproject "servlet-context.xml" & "root-context.xml" error

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

i downloaded    3.8.3(64) sts tools zip file and i try to crate my first springmvcproject i get errors "servlet-context.xml" and "root-context.xml" compiler didn't show any error but show me red sign on corner of the files. I try to run show I got the error 404. how fixed the problem

edit: here is screenshot

http://www.flickr.com/photos/94224113@N04/8574687076/in/photostream/lightbox/

Comment: You need to provide more information, give us a screen shot if needed

Comment: screen shot http://www.flickr.com/photos/94224113@N04/8573573847/in/photostream/lightbox/

Comment: Open those files and post a screen shot of what its complaining about.

Comment: here http://www.flickr.com/photos/94224113@N04/8574687076/in/photostream/lightbox/

Answer (score 0):

```
**root-context.xml File**


    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

   <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schema" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean> 
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.comp.project.serviceImpl" /> 

    <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>        
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.comp.project.Domain"/>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>  
             <!--    <prop key="hibernate.SQL">TRACE</prop> 
                <prop key="hibernate.type">TRACE</prop>  -->

            </props>        
        </property>
    </bean>    
  <!--   <context:annotation-config/> -->    
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.comp.project.repository"
                      entity-manager-factory-ref="emf"
                      transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/> 
   </beans>



**Servlet-context.xml**


<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->
     <context:annotation-config />
    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <!-- <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> -->

    <mvc:resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.comp.project" />

    <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="home" />

    <interceptors>
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor" />
         <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor"
            p:paramName="lang" /> 
    </interceptors>

    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
        id="messageSource" p:basenames="WEB-INF/i18n/messages"
        p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false" />
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver"
        id="localeResolver" p:cookieName="locale" />
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource"
        id="themeSource" />
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver"
        id="themeResolver" p:cookieName="theme" p:defaultThemeName="standard" />
    <!-- Enable file upload functionality -->
    <beans:bean id="multipartResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

<!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
<!--  <bean:property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />  -->
</beans:bean>


</beans:beans>
```